# how to import excel data with datetime variable into sas?

Tags: sas

sample data

```
time            sales        
 7/21/2010 13:00    3257.959
 7/21/2010 13:30    3211.445
 7/21/2010 14:00    3169.257
 7/21/2010 14:30    3144.332
```

how to import this type format data into sas. My file is in xls(excel).

Comment: Not sure any inbuilt format would read the data in time variable in date format , I would suggest use infile statement and read the data in time in char format and then convert it in date format.

Comment: I suggest you to import it as a string and process it in a second time in a datastep, use substring for catching the date and the time in sas format and build the final value using DHMS function, put 0 to seconds.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use ANYDTDTM informat to read in your datetime variable.

```
data have;
infile datalines missover;
input time anydtdtm18.  sales  8. ;
format time DATETIME18.;
datalines;
7/21/2010 13:00    3257.959
7/21/2010 13:30    3211.445
7/21/2010 14:00    3169.257
7/21/2010 14:30    3144.332
;;;;
run;
proc print data=have;run;
```